# Blender 2.82 UV size changes when texture is loaded

Tags: texturing, uv, dimensions

I have this problem: let's say I have simple rectangle like this

[image]

When I create UV map for it, it sets the UV dimensions nicely to size of the actual rectangle and all is fine

[image]

Now as soon as I load any texture to it it changes its size/dimensions like this

[image]

Do you see how ugly it stretches the UV map?

What I want is to let the original UV size untouched so that I can set the image dimensions right to fit into UV dimensions according to it, and not UV map stretches to image so that the actual UV size is not the same as rectangle size anymore and I can never get the actual texture (image) dimensions right.

Basically I want to set the texture size manually to fit into the UV size that must stay the same as rectangle dimensions (the same size ti has when initially created).

I know I can move the handles of the UV map but that is exactly what I cannot do as I am doing/creating it for another SW where it matters what dimensions the actual UV has (it needs to be EXACTLY as the rectangle dimensions)!

Comment: Why not just scale the UV to fit the texture?

Comment: This used to be a case not only for 2.82, but for 2.7x versions as well. Unwrap after opening an image in UV editor, not before. Otherwise UV map will be changed to correlate to changed dimensions of texture space. This is one of reasons to use square images for texture maps

Comment: @ChristopherBennett because I am creating rectangle with UV map that I will export as OBJ file that will be used in other software that which create special file out of it to use it in yet another 3D-CAD-like software. Therefore I need it to be exactly the same dimensions as the rectangle. Thus changing the size of the UV is not an option for me.